# Getting Cuda code from Tensorflow or Keras

Tags: tensorflow

I have a code in Keras (or its TF version). I want to have a CUDA code which is equivalence to it. Is there a way to get it?

I know that from Keras I can look at the basic graph topology using the following code:

```
# LSTM for sequence classification in the IMDB dataset
import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 5000
max_review_length = 500
# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

g = K.get_session().graph
# GIVES THE GRAPH TOPOLOGY!:
graph_def = g.as_graph_def()
```

Is there a way to have the .cc file that represent this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no functionality in TensorFlow to generate C++ CUDA source code from a graph, but the [XLA framework](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/) supports [ahead-of-time compilation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/tfcompile), which generates efficient bytecode from your TensorFlow graph, which you can then execute on your CUDA-capable GPU.

Comment: Actually, for research purposes, I'm looking for the cuda code, not compiled version. So, how the tensorflow do it? On one hand there is a python code, and on the other hand we have compiled code. 

1) What are the stages in the process to transform the python to cuda?
2) Is there any documentation for it?

Comment: Neither approach transforms the Python into CUDA. Instead you use Python to build a `tf.GraphDef` protocol buffer that represents the computation as a dataflow graph. The standard TensorFlow runtime will interpret the graph and issue pre-compiled CUDA kernels for each operation. XLA will take the same graph and generate LLVM bitcode, without an intermediate C++ compilation step. The best documentation for XLA is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/